# ChallengedUri выдал исключение

Tags: c#, get, httpwebrequest

Основной код:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://tele2.ru/api/subscribers/номер_телефона/rests");//status=connected
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.CookieContainer.Add(new Uri("https://login.tele2.ru/ssotele2/wap/auth"), cook);
request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8";
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36";
request.ContentType = "application/json;charset=utf-8";
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
request.Headers.Add("DNT", "1");
request.Method = "GET";
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync())
{
    using (var read = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var result = await read.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
}
```

Исключение выдает здесь:

```
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вопрос: из-за чего это возникает? Как исправить? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Убрал блок `try{} catch{}`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выглядит как баг во фреймворке. [Это](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36475310/276994)?

Comment: Исходя из обсуждения по ссылке, вы случайно не компилируете на сетевом диске?

Comment: @VladD, нет, компилирую не на сетевом диске. Прикрепил другой скрин, для большей информации.

Comment: А где само исключение то?

Comment: @Monk, не понял. Код в 1-ом посте, на какой строке исключение там же.

Comment: В локальных должна быть переменная $exception в момент исключения, её бы увидеть и её стектрейс.

Comment: @Monk, посмотрите пост, добавил. А stackTrace имеет тип `object {sbyte[]}` и содержит цифры.
`

Comment: У вас ошибка 400 и явная текстовка, что запрос недопустимый. Сайт теле2 ваш запрос явно не принял, разбирайтесь с формированием правильного запроса.